# How to scroll with programming within Vuetify Virtual Scroller?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have used this Vuetify component https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/virtual-scroller/ to make a virtual scroll within a card, but now I need to go to a specific scroll element when my hook mount is executed component vue.

How could I do that, thank you in advance for your help?

I am a native of Spanish therefore my English is a bit bad.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also: https://es.stackoverflow.com/ :)